# Matplotlib sequentially printing /append to image

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, matplotlib, dataset

Currently, I have a huge dataset, which did not fit in memory. For training, I used the tf.Dataset to train my neural network. Unfortunately, now I want to verify my results but the dataset + printing do not fit into my 32 GB of memory. Is there a way to partially or sequential print a graph or multiple graphs to a file using matplotlib. So after each predict_on_batch I would draw a part of the graph (load image, draw, save image). In the end, I want a complete graph to verify my results. Any ideas or solutions to the "data do not fit in memory, but I need a graph to visualize it"-problem would be appreciated. It is not labeled data so there is no way besides checking it visually.

Comment: What are you trying to graph? As in what variables do you want on the x and y axes? It's rare to need the entire dataset to produce a graph, usually you use summary statistics like RMSE on the test set etc?

Comment: Well, I search for patterns in the MSE of the prediction. But, the patterns are not known beforehand.

Comment: So what variables do you want on the x and y axes? MSE on y and training epoch on the x?

Comment: batch number on x, mses on y

Comment: Can you post your code then (or ideally just the relevant training bit)? This information is usually already captured by TF during the training process, so there's often no need to build up your own lists.

Comment: well as far as i know model.evaluate gives you only an average mse over all batches, but i need an mse value per fed line. I have a dataset of (>1m, 32 batches, 1800 lines, 540 cols). I want the mse values of 1m * 32 * 1800 and want that printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way I would approach this problem is to save the information in a list instead of a partial plot.

I am assuming you want your pipeline to look like this:

1. create empty plot
2. predict on batch
3. plot new results
4. repeat steps 2 and 3

What I would suggest looks something like this:

1. initialize empty lists
2. predict on batch
3. append the results to lists
4. repeat steps 2 and 3
5. plot the final arrays

Comment: Followed your way and created a CSV, and keep appending the results. Thank you. I thought there would be another way, but why do make things complicated :D